# Are there alternatives after the official support time stops?

Tags: security, server, updates, alternative

I'm currently running Ubuntu 8.10 on a system. It works very good but I did a lot of tuning (it's a server) to get it working. I'm aware that I need to upgrade to a new LTS version of Ubuntu if I have time.

But until I have time for that, are there alternative ways to get some (albeit unofficial) security updates from a secondary source?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't imagine you will find a repository that continues supplying security updates after a release has reached its "end of life." It's just too much work for something that has no future.

That said, even after the official repository has been discontinued, you can still access the old repo for the purpose of installing new programs, ect... Also, this can be important for when you find time to do the upgrade as you should make sure that all of your packages have been correctly updated to the release’s final versions before doing the upgrade. I'm not sure, but the `do-release-upgrade` script might very well choke if it can not find the repository for the release that you are *upgrading from*.

After "end of life," the repositories are mirrored at `old-releases.ubuntu.com`. So you should change your your `sources.list` to look for:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ intrepid main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ intrepid-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ intrepid-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ intrepid-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Comment: Thanks, I had hoped that there was some kind of debian repository that could be used instead. But the ubuntu changes are probably too big. Or maybe there would a community to maintain some older version, much like there is a community to do CentOS instead of RHEL.

Answer (score 0):

far as I know, I have to say no, ubuntu only supports active official distributions, ubuntu security updates off when these distributions finish their period of activity, and not found anywhere else, it is recommended that you migrate your system to a new version when you have time for security reasons .......